# Matrix norm inequality involving max and stacked matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality

In a paper I found the following inequality for matrices $A$ and $B$:

$\max\left\{||A||, ||B||\right\} \le \left\| \begin{align}A \\ B\end{align} \right\|_2 $

I suspect that this is a well-known inequality, which I just did not happen to find. Can somebody point me to the proof for this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\| \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} \| = \sqrt{\| \begin{bmatrix} A^* & B^* \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}\|} = \sqrt{ \| A^*A + B^*B\|}$.

Since $A^*A, B^*B$ are positive semi-definite Hermitian matrices, we have $A^*A + B^*B \ge A^*A$ and similarly for $B^*B$. In particular, we have $\| A^*A + B^*B\| \ge \|A^* A \|$ and similarly for $B^*B$. Since $\sqrt{\|A^*A\|} = \|A\|$, we have the desired result.

**Addendum**: Note that $\|A\|^2 = \lambda_\max (A^*A)$. Furthermore,
$\lambda_\max (A^*A+ B^*B) \|x\|^2 \ge \langle x, (A^*A + B^*B) x \rangle  \ge \langle x, A^*A  x \rangle$. If we choose $x$ to be a unit eigenvector of $A^*A$ corresponding to $\lambda_\max (A^*A)$, then we obtain 
$\lambda_\max (A^*A+ B^*B) \ge \lambda_\max (A^*A)$. And so we obtain
$\| A^*A + B^*B\| \ge \|A^* A \|$

Comment: That was fast, thanks! What I don't get is how you follow $||A^∗A+B^∗B||≥||A^∗A||$ from $A^* A + B^* B \ge A^* A$.

Comment: @user105685: I added some details above.

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$
\|A\|_2\leq\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}
\leq\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\sqrt{\|Ax\|_2^2+\|Bx\|_2^2}}{\|x\|_2}
=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A\\ B\end{bmatrix}x\right\|_2}{\|x\|_2}
=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2.
$$
Switch $A$ and $B$ to get $$\|B\|_2\leq\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2.$$